# Implementing grep in c using system calls

Tags: c, grep, system-calls

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void match_pattern(char *argv[])
{
    int fd,r,j=0;
    char temp,line[100];
    if((fd=open(argv[2],O_RDONLY)) != -1)
    {
        while((r=read(fd,&temp,sizeof(char)))!= 0)
        {
            if(temp!='\n')
            {
                line[j]=temp;
                j++;
            }
            else
            {
                if(strstr(line,argv[1])!=NULL)
                    printf("%s\n",line);
                memset(line,0,sizeof(line));
                j=0;
            }

        }
    }   
}

main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    struct stat stt;
    if(argc==3)
    {
        if(stat(argv[2],&stt)==0)
            match_pattern(argv);
        else 
        {
            perror("stat()");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Contents of file:

```
arunds ghh
sdf
hi
hello dude
am arun
```

My output:

```
./mygrep arun file
arunds ghh
am arun
```

Am getting correct output

Content of file:

```
arun arundfdf arun
arunds ghh
sdf
```

My output:

```
./mygrep arun file
arun arundfdf arun �5
arunds ghh
```

I have no idea why some unwanted characters getting printed.

Comment: If performance is of any interest, read to buffer, and then get from buffer char-by-char. Overhead of read() is really quite big. So basically, reimplement stdio getchar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never NULL-terminate your `line` buffer, so it will overflow after the end. Run the `memset` call also after you declared the `line` variable.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I added line[j]='\0' above  if(strstr(line,argv[1])!=NULL)

Answer (score 0):

You need to null-terminate the `line` but why do you read it one character at a time ? you could read whole lines with `fgets()` which will null-terminate the buffer for you:

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
   if (strstr(line, argv[1])) {
    ...
   }
}
```

Also this will make sure you don't overflow the 100 bytes buffer you allocate.

Comment: @BartFriederichs yup that's another issue.

Comment: actually I need to use only system calls

Comment: @user1958241 those are not system calls, those are functions in the standard C library even read() is a function :) anyway, at least make sure you don't read more than 99 bytes

Comment: As far as i know, fgets() is a function and it is in Standard C but read() is a unix system call.

Comment: @user1958241 `read()` is just a wrapper that calls the kernel and passes the read system call number and arguments, I'm sure your assignment doesn't require using real system calls. see this if you want to understand the difference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668747/system-call-vs-function-call