# unable to write into file using c , with unix system calls

Tags: c, unix

I am working on `unix system calls`.
I want to read the `string` from `standard input` using `read()` and then write it to the file using `write()`.

I am able to `open` the file , `read` the `string` from `standard input` , but unable to `write` it to the file.

my code is :

```
#include <unistd.h>     // to remove WARNINGS LIKE  warning: implicit declaration of       function ‘read’ , warning: implicit declaration of function ‘write’
#include<fcntl.h>         /* defines options flags */
#include<sys/types.h>     /* defines types used by sys/stat.h */
#include<sys/stat.h>      /* defines S_IREAD & S_IWRITE  */
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
 {
 int fd,readd;
 char *buf[1024]; 


    fd = open("myfile",O_RDWR);
    if(fd != -1)
         printf("open error\n");
    else
    {
        // read i\p from stdin , and write it to myfile.txt

            if((readd=read(0,buf,sizeof(buf)))<0)
              printf("read error\n");
            else
             {
                    printf("\n%s",buf);
                    printf("\n%d",readd);
                if(write(fd,buf,readd) != readd)
                      printf("write error\n");

              }
    } 

return 0;
}
```

the output is

```
    write error
```

it is working properly , if I `write` the `string` to `standard output`

Question :

1) what is the problem with `write()` ?

2) I want to include newline character `\n` at the end of the line. How is it possible through `standard input`?

Comment: Instead of `char *buf[1024]` you probably want `char buf[1024]`.

Comment: Check the `errno` variable.

Comment: Instead of `printf("write error")`, use something like `perror("write")`. That shows you which error occurred.

Comment: it gives me the error `Bad file descriptor` , which means these `file descriptor` is not valid , but what to do sir? I am not giving the `file descriptor`.

Comment: all the things mentioned below , is corrected . but it still not writing what I write in `standard input` , It writes `kkcmvdksvdslvdvldzvd`.

Comment: As a side note: You are not using any system calls here, only the C standard library (See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668747/system-call-vs-function-call)). And please don't format `kind-of-technical-sounding-terms` like `code`, it's makes it very hard to read.

Answer (score 3):

```
fd = open("myfile",O_RDWR);
```

This opens an existing file. If the file does not exist, you get an error.
You can use perror() to get more descriptions of the error.

```
fd = open("myfile",O_RDWR);
if (fd == -1) {
   perror("open failed");
   exit(1);
}
```

The error here is that your error checking logic is wrong.

```
if(fd != -1)
     printf("open error\n");
```

Should be

```
if(fd == -1)
     printf("open error\n"); //or better yet, perror("open error");
```

Once that is corrected, you will still get an error when opening the file if the file does not already exist. To also create the file, you need an additional flag, and give it proper permissions:

```
fd = open("myfile",O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0664);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(fd != -1)
     printf("open error\n");
```

This doesn't look right. If your output isn't "open error", then it probably means that your call to `open` failed, because you only attempt write to the file when you've failed to open it.

A good idea is to print the errno when printing errors, print the errors to stderr, not stdout and exit immediately on error. Try using `perror` for printing error messages.

Also, I don't like this comment:

```
#include <unistd.h>     // to remove WARNINGS LIKE  warning: implicit declaration of       function ‘read’ , warning: implicit declaration of function ‘write’
```

The include isn't needed to "remove warnings". It's needed to make your program correct.