# is open a function or a system call? (select all valid answers)

Tags: c, linux

I have been given this question:

Is `open` a function or a system call? (select all valid answers)

a) it’s a function provided by the kernel

b) it’s a function

c) it’s a library call

d) it’s a system call

e) it’s a kernel routine

I have selected options a) and d) but the answer is still wrong. Any insight, please.

Comment: Type `man open` at a linux command prompt (or on google) and find it yourself.
Hint: it's on man section #2 so take your conclusions.

Comment: Also take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668747/system-call-vs-function-call

Comment: a) false.  the kernel function is sys_open.

Comment: Why does it matter if `open()` is a "function" or a "system call"?  if someone stridently insists that, "`open()` is a system call!" you need to ask them, "Why isn't `fopen()` also a "system call" then?" Make sure you have a stopwatch to time how long they have their mouth open, speechless.  Both `open()` and `fopen()` are **functions** that will wind up making the `openat()` system call - note that's **not** the `open()` system call - `openat()` has been the POSIX standard for almost two decades now.  The "function" vs "system call" distinction is artificial, useless, and irrelevant.

Comment: open is a variable.  open() is a function.

Comment: @Chenmunka -- a peculiar objection. In C `open()` may be a function _call_ if `open` takes no arguments, and  `open` may be a function designator. But you seem to be commenting on a typographical convention (not part of the C language) used by some, but certainly not by everyone, to indicate that an identifier refers to a function.

Answer (score 2):

Just a little bit of non-conformism here.

Calling `open` on any Unix-like does end in a system call using exactly the passed parameter. For that reason it is said to be a system call.

But with some nifty-picking, we can say that it can be a tiny function wrapping the actual system call.

The man page for [`syscall`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/syscall) is explicit about that point:

> syscall() is a small library function that invokes the system call...

But in the context of the question (yes/no type question), this understanding is not the expected answer, even if it is perfectly correct...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is not so simple as the question. It is open to interpretation.

`open` is a function [in `glibc`], but it is also the name of the corresponding syscall.

This seems like an interview related question. Or, some certification test question. Or, a test question from some programming course.

But, IMO, it's poorly worded without more (such) context, and the answer depends upon some interpretation of how sophisticated an answer is required.

The TL;DR is probably: `B`, `C`, and `D`.

But, `A` and `E` are also possible in some contexts ... ;-)

So, we need the context: *The mayonaise you like is the mayonaise you grew up with ...* :-)

---

> b) it’s a function

**Yes**, it's a function that is linked from `glibc`

---

> c) it’s a library call

**Yes**, because it is a function in `glibc`

However, ***if*** the definition of "library call" is *only* a function in `glibc` that does *not* invoke a syscall, then the answer is **No**.

---

> a) it’s a function provided by the kernel

For many syscalls, (e.g. `open`, `close`, `read`, `write`) the kernel does *not* provide a function to userspace, so the answer is **No**.

However, for *some* kernel syscalls, the kernel *does* inject a function into userspace via the `VDSO` mechanism. See: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSO

An example of this is `clock_gettime`. Under a simple implementation, the function invokes a syscall. But, for speed, the kernel injects code into the app, and the library function knows this, and just invokes the injected code which has special access to some portions of kernel memory that are mapped (R/O) into userspace.

So, the answer is: **It depends**

---

> d) it’s a system call

In most cases, the TL;DR answer is **Yes**, it's a system call.

But, the library function is considered to be a [thin] "wrapper" function around the kernel's syscall.

Here, the underlying implementation would be an internal version of:

```
syscall(SYS_open,...)
```

So, the "syscall" is `SYS_open`

So, the answer *could* be: **No**, `open` is just a [`glibc`] library function [that invokes the `SYS_open` syscall].

---

> e) it’s a kernel routine

The answer is **No**.

But, because when the kernel receives an `int 0x80`, `syscall`, or `sysenter`, it dispatches to a given handler function in the kernel.

The convention for a given syscall (e.g.) `whatever` is `sys_whatever`. So, the kernel [internally] calls `sys_open`, which probably calls `do_open`.

So, under a loose interpretation, the kernel *does* have a function for this. So, the answer could be **Yes**

---

So, the question was probably posed for the "simple" interpretation:

**B**, **C**, **D**

(and *sometimes* **A**)

Answer (score 1):

is open a function or a system call? (select all valid answers)

```
it’s a function

it’s a function provided by the kernel

it’s a system call
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).